# On checkbox checked show radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I would like to ask for a little help here, since I haven't got any big knowledge in Javascript, nor in jQuery. I need to show 5 radio buttons when a checkbox is checked, the checkboxes represent languages that the user speaks, so for each of the selected, there should appear 5 separate radio buttons for how good they speak it(1 to 5). I tried to do it with jQuery, but I did not manage to get very far away...

This is where my checkboxes are created(dynamically):

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < Model.Languages.Count; i++)
          { %>

        <input id="applang" name="applang" type="checkbox" value="<%: Model.Languages[i].languageID%>" />

        <%: Model.Languages[i].name.ToString() %><br />

        <%} %>
```

So, I tried to add this script, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$("input[@name='applang']").click(function () {

    $("input[type='radio']").show();

});
```

I also tried this way - to use this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
      else
          e.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

And it works, but it works on already present controls, and I guess I need to create mine dynamically, or maybe not? And I tried to hide a present control with CSS, but then when the script shows it, it is there, only invisible :)

Also, I would want to get the name and value of the radio buttons from my database, i.e. Model(this is ASP.NET MVC)..  Can someone help me a little bit, please?

Comment: u can use the radiolist and checkboxlist helpers from here: http://awesome.codeplex.com and use the parentId to bind them togheter

Answer (score 1):

`ID`s are meant to be unique. That is causing your issue.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your answer, nor that you understand my question...My issue is to create radio buttons on click on a checkbox. And the ID part is another issue, but for that later. Thanks for the answer, anyhow. Regards

Comment: He means this line `<input id="applang"` creates multiple checkboxes with the same id. You should change it to something that creates unique IDs for each checkbox.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry about that. Well, it has to be that way, 'cause I am pulling those in the controller like this: string demoStringArray = Request.Form["applang"]; If the names were different, how would I get them?

Comment: `name` and `id` are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You could put the controls that you want to show and hide inside of a div then just show or hide the div as necessary.

Comment: Why, let me try that and I'll write here whether it succeeded or not. Thank you for the answer anyhow. Regards

Comment: Oh, but sorry - I want the div to be hidden at first, then when I check the checkbox I want to make it visible. But if I go for CSS hidden in the beginning, then my Javascript would put it physically there, but it would be invisible..

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issue with `Id` already stated.

> So, I tried to add this script, but
>   it's not working:

Assuming you are using a version of jQuery later than 1.2 the use of `@` in the selector is invalid, also make sure the script is wrapped in `$(function(){});`

```
  $(function(){
    $("input[name='applang']").click(function() {
        $("input[type='radio']").show();
    });
  });
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Wn4SK/).**

> And it works, but it works on already
>   present controls, and I guess I need
>   to create mine dynamically, or maybe
>   not? And I tried to hide a present
>   control with CSS, but then when the
>   script shows it, it is there, only
>   invisible :)

If by this you mean that they are appended after the document has finished loading you will need to use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (or delegate) so you can target elements that have yet been added to the dom.

```
  $(function(){
    $("input[name='applang']").live("click", function() {
        $("input[type='radio']").show();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I can see what you mean.. The ID issue is a pretty serious one. I used your advice to create this script to hide the div containing the radio buttons when the page is loaded(ready) and then on a click on a checkbox it is visible again. But now it becomes visible(the first div, cause there are as many divs as there are checkboxes) - the first div becomes visible on click on any of the checkboxes, so I check the 3 checkbox, and the first div changes, not the third:  $(document).ready(function () {
        var r = document.getElementById('radioDiv');
        r.style.display = 'none';
    });

Answer (score 0):

Just to put the answer here, so that someone else can use it, although I'm not very proud with the current implementation, it is not a very pretty code, but it still works...

The checkboxes and radiobuttons - separated in groups with unique Group IDs, so that the first checkbox can control the first radiobutton list etc...

```
 <% for(int i = 0; i < Model.Languages.Count; i++)
          { %>
            <% int count = i+1; %>
        <input id="applang" onclick="toggle_visibility('radioDiv<%:+count %>');" name="applang" type="checkbox" value="<%: Model.Languages[i].languageID%>" />

        <%: Model.Languages[i].name.ToString() %>

        <div id="radioDiv<%:+count %>"><input name="weigthRadio<%:+count %>" type="radio" value="2"/>Dovolen<input type="radio" name="weigthRadio<%:+count %>" value="3" />Dobar<input type="radio" name="weigthRadio<%:+count %>" value="4" />Mnogu dobar<input type="radio" name="weigthRadio<%:+count %>" value="5" />Odlicen</div>
        <br />

        <%} %>
```

Four individual pieces of code doing just the same: hiding the radiobutton lists on start:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = document.getElementById('radioDiv1');
    r.style.display = 'none';
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = document.getElementById('radioDiv2');
    r.style.display = 'none';
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = document.getElementById('radioDiv3');
    r.style.display = 'none';
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    var r = document.getElementById('radioDiv4');
    r.style.display = 'none';
});
```

And the function that's called on click on the checkboxes, that toggles visibility:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function toggle_visibility(id) {
      var e = document.getElementById(id);
      if (e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
      else
          e.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

This is the client-side code, in the back there's some pretty wild